# Boolean function returns default value until real value checked in Firebase DB XCode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I've the following boolean function:

```
func checkIfLocateAcessGiven(uid: String) -> Bool {
    
    print("checkIfLocateAcessGiven")
    
    var currentUserID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "currentUserID")
    
    var statusStr = false
    
    print("checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 1: \(statusStr)")
    
    Database.database().reference().child("Locate").child(currentUserID!)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (dataSnapshot) in
        
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("RequestedTo")){
                    
                    if(dataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "RequestedTo").hasChild(uid)){
                        
                        var status = dataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "RequestedTo").childSnapshot(forPath: uid).value as! String ?? ""
                        
                        if(status == "true"){
                            
                            statusStr = true
                            
                            print("checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 2: \(statusStr)")
                            
                        }else {
                            
                            statusStr = false
                            
                            print("checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 3: \(statusStr)")
                        }
                        
                    }else {
                        
                        statusStr = false
                        
                        print("checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 4: \(statusStr)")
                    }
                    
                }else {
                    
                    statusStr = false
                    
                    print("checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 5: \(statusStr)")
                }
                
            }else {
                
                statusStr = false
                
                print("checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 6: \(statusStr)")
            }
            
    })
    
    print("checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 7: \(statusStr)")
    
    return statusStr
    
}
```

When I call this function I get the following results:

```
checkIfLocateAcessGiven
checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 1: false
checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 7: false
checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 2: true
```

Since **false** is returned at first, my code takes a different flow, and later **true** is returned, how can I wait in the boolean function until the real value is checked. There's delay of approx. 1 second between

```
checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 7: false
```

and

```
checkIfLocateAcessGiven statusStr 2: true
```

I want the boolean to wait and check the real value and then return the value, in this case **true** but it's currently returning **false**

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an asynchronous function, meaning that it cannot return synchronously a result which it needs to obtain asynchronously, for example from a web service, like Firebase.

You can't (or rather shouldn't) wait for it, and instead use a callback to notify when the value has been obtained.

If you don't know about async programming, there are a lot of material online and you should definitely read more about it, because this answer won't be comprehensive.

The basic idea is that your async function takes in a closure that would be invoked on completion:

```
func checkIfLocateAcessGiven(uid: String, completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
   // your setup code

   Database.database().reference().child("Locate").child(currentUserID!)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (dataSnapshot) in
         // checks, ifs, etc..

             // whenever you have the result
             completion(true) // or completion(false)

   }
}
```

The caller would specify the completion callback, which would be invoked asynchronously:

```
print("before")
checkIfLocateAcessGiven(uid: "1234") { result in
   print("async call result: ", result) 
   // do whatever you need to do with the result
}
print("after")
```

The output of the above would be something like this:

```
before
after
async call result: true
```

The first two lines would print immediately one after another, and the third line would take a while, however long the Firebase call takes.

Comment: I didn't know how to obtain value asynchronously. This really helped me. Thank You!